# Is there an upgrade to Leif's shop?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Is there some sort of upgrade to Leif's shop? If so, how can I achieve it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, Leif's shop becomes upgraded as part of the Nooklings' shop upgrades.  When you unlock T.I.Y., the two will merge, and from there they share upgrades.

The first level of the upgrade will add two plantable "bush" plants you can buy daily, plus one "furniture" plant like Bonsai and other potted plants.

Comment: Added info about what the shop gets at the TIY upgrade. Not sure what it gets when there's a second upgrade.

Comment: I think the fertiliser comes in the second upgrade - since I haven't seen that in my first-upgrade-level shop, and I know it exists since you need to buy it for one of the golden tools (shovel, I think?)